# How to setState in react.js using "binance.futuresMiniTickerStream()" function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, websocket, binance

When I do this It works

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// Node Binance API
// https://github.com/binance-exchange/node-binance-api

const Binance = require('node-binance-api')
const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  APISECRET: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
})

// BTCUSDT - price
const FuturesPrices = () => {

  const [btcPrice, setBtcPrice] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

      async function fetchMyAPI() {

        let response = await binance.futuresPrices()

        response = response.BTCUSDT

        setBtcPrice(response)

        //console.log(response)
      }

      fetchMyAPI()

    }, [btcPrice])

    return <div>{btcPrice}</div>

}

export default FuturesPrices
```

---

But when I try example down below It doesn't work. Gives "error
Unhandled Rejection (Error): ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object"

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// Node Binance API
// https://github.com/binance-exchange/node-binance-api

const Binance = require('node-binance-api')
const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  APISECRET: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
})

// BTCUSDT - price
const BtcPriceTicker = () => {

  const [btcPriceTicker, setBtcPriceTicker] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

      async function fetchMyAPI() {

        let response = await binance.futuresMiniTickerStream( 'BTCUSDT' )

        response = response.close

        setBtcPriceTicker(response)

        //console.log(response)
      }

      fetchMyAPI()

    }, [btcPriceTicker])

    return <div>{btcPriceTicker}</div>

}

export default BtcPriceTicker;
```

*My GitHub
https://github.com/React-Binance/react-binance-api
Contribute to React-Binance/functional components development*

Comment: Other than the effect not [cleaning up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) and you trying to dump a JavaScript object in jsx (use `<div>{JSON.stringify(btcPrice,undefined,2)}</div>` instead) and your code indentation is off, I don't see a problem with the code. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've rephrased my question. Please take a look. I'm new to react, can you tell me where and how to use cleaning with functional components

Answer (score 1):

By passing `[btcPrice]` in the dependency array, you're telling react to run this effect if the value of `btcPrice` changes.

Form [Official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

> You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders. To do so, pass an array as an optional second argument to useEffect

You can pass an empty array instead, which will make `useEffect` run only once like `componentDidMount`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've rephrased my question. Please take a look